# Passing django-recurrence field via REST API

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Folks,
I am using django recurrence field in my app and its not clear how to format the field when passed via REST API.

Any help is appreciated.

```
from recurrence.fields import RecurrenceField

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recurrences = RecurrenceField()
```

Comment: I figured I can reverse engineer by creating the field using admin UI but looking for understanding the format, so can generate via another app, not  written in Django.

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "recurrences": "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20190131T080000Z;BYDAY=TU,TH,FR",
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its based of RFC 2445
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.8.5.4

Format Definition: This property is defined by the following
notation:

```
 rrule      = "RRULE" rrulparam ":" recur CRLF

 rrulparam  = *(";" xparam)
```

Example: All examples assume the Eastern United States time zone.

Daily for 10 occurrences:

```
 DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970902T090000
 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10

 ==> (1997 9:00 AM EDT)September 2-11
```

Daily until December 24, 1997:

```
 DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970902T090000
 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=19971224T000000Z

 ==> (1997 9:00 AM EDT)September 2-30;October 1-25
     (1997 9:00 AM EST)October 26-31;November 1-30;December 1-23
```

Every other day - forever:

```
 DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970902T090000
 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2
 ==> (1997 9:00 AM EDT)September2,4,6,8...24,26,28,30;
      October 2,4,6...20,22,24
     (1997 9:00 AM EST)October 26,28,30;November 1,3,5,7...25,27,29;
      Dec 1,3,...
```